# Elements in a list which added from a file is not identified as a list element

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 productName = input("\nProduct Name: ")
        productName = productName.lower()

        if productName in allProducts:
            k=allProducts.index(productName)
            currentStock = allLevels[k]

            stockLevel = input("Stock Level: ")

            if stockLevel.isdigit():
                stockLevel = int(stockLevel)+int(currentStock)
                allLevels[k]=stockLevel
                print(productName, "has been updated with a stock of", stockLevel, "products\n")
            else:
                print("*** Error: Incorrect value entered") 
        else:
            print("*** Error: Product not listed")
```

**this is the code, The productName is I entered is not matching with the data in the list, Which is actually present in the list. It directly go to: 
                else:
                print("*** Error: Product not listed")
Why the if loop is not working?**

this is the output:

```
Widgets

 Fidgets

 Didgets

 Pidgets

Product Name: widgets
*** Error: Product not listed
```

Comment: Where is the list of products in your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to make a [mre]. The code you posted will not run since it's incomplete and not indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

The below given code is working fine for me with the dummy **allProducts** and **allLevels** lists.

It looks like in your case that productName.lower() creating issues, seems you have capitalize or sentence case values in your list while .lower() converting input() value 
to lower case.
you can verify by removing that .lower() from productName.lower()-

enter code here

```
allProducts = ["widgets", "test1", "test2"]
allLevels = ["a", "b", "c"]

productName = input("\nProduct Name: ")
productName = productName.lower()

if productName in allProducts:
   k=allProducts.index(productName)
   currentStock = allLevels[k]

   stockLevel = input("Stock Level: ")
   if stockLevel.isdigit():
      stockLevel = int(stockLevel)+int(currentStock)
      allLevels[k]=stockLevel
      print(productName, "has been updated with a stock of", stockLevel,     "products\n")
  else:
      print("*** Error: Incorrect value entered") 
else:
  print("*** Error: Product not listed")
```